# WPF element host is crashing every second time

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls, crash

I have a WPF user control inside windows form project and I have a problem. Every second time my app crashes as element host can't load data in user control.

Same thing happens when I put this in WPF project. Every second time my app starts normally.

Any idea what could be the problem? This is my user control code:

```
<UserControl x:Class="Fleet_management.Info"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
             mc:Ignorable="d" Height="492" Width="578">
    <UserControl.Background>
        <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
            <GradientStop Color="#FFE2E2E2" Offset="0" />
            <GradientStop Color="White" Offset="1" />
        </LinearGradientBrush>
    </UserControl.Background>

    <UserControl.Resources>
        <XmlDataProvider x:Key="rssData" XPath="//item" Source="******" />
    </UserControl.Resources>

    <Grid Margin="3" Height="598" Width="565">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="252*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="90*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="223*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="177*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="55*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="122*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="177*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <ListBox x:Name="lstItems" Margin="3,0" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource rssData}}"
                 SelectedIndex="0" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" FontStretch="Normal" FontSize="14" FontFamily="Lucida Sans Unicode" Grid.ColumnSpan="3">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <Image Width="20" Margin="3" Source="{Binding XPath=enclosure/@url}" />
                        <TextBlock Margin="3" VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding XPath=title}" FontWeight="Bold" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>

        <StackPanel Grid.Row="1" Orientation="Vertical" DataContext="{Binding ElementName=lstItems, Path=SelectedItem}" Margin="0,0,0,5" Grid.ColumnSpan="3">
            <TextBlock Margin="3" FontSize="13" FontWeight="Bold" Text="{Binding XPath=title, Path=InnerText}" />
            <TextBlock Margin="3" Opacity="0.72" Text="{Binding XPath=pubDate}" />
        </StackPanel>
        <ScrollViewer CanContentScroll="True" Grid.Row="2" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"  DataContext="{Binding ElementName=lstItems, Path=SelectedItem}" Margin="0,0,3,115" Grid.RowSpan="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="3">
            <TextBlock  Margin="3"
                       FontStyle="Italic" Text="{Binding XPath=description, Path=InnerText}" TextWrapping="Wrap" TextAlignment="Justify" AllowDrop="False"
                       Foreground="#FF0000E7" FontFamily="Lucida Sans Unicode" FontSize="14" Padding="0,0,5,0" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
        </ScrollViewer>

    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to check if the xml document that contains the data is still locked by the previous app.

So, start up the app. Close it. [Check to see if the xml file is still in use.](http://ask-leo.com/how_can_i_find_out_who_is_using_a_file_in_use.html)

Also,: add exception handling so you know what exception is being thrown. Use at least [Application.DispatherUnhandledException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.application.dispatcherunhandledexception.aspx)

Comment: source is read from the internet website it is rss reader. How can I put exception handling while this is probbably loaded at runtime. I used WPF element host control in the toolbox and set to load certain user control.

Comment: I was referring to testing it in the WPF app.

Comment: problem is that I am new to WPF and this is why this probably happens, I have probably forgot to dispose something. Can you try to run my code? You can put some rss link that you want, It would probably work

Comment: I used `http://wpfwonderland.wordpress.com/feed/` as rss source and it works every time. Can you test with this url?

Comment: hmm, it starts normal eveytime