# How to load and refresh user control on button click

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls, load, refresh

I have a windows form application and one of the control on the form is WPF user control.
I have put element host control on the windows form and this is loading my user control at startup.

What I want is to load and refresh user control at certain time. As I need fresh data to be loaded.

I have tried `elementHost1.Refresh();` and this is not doing anything.

How can I load and refresh this?

This is my user control on this [LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10765116/wpf-element-host-is-crashing-every-second-time)

Comment: Guys you can simply try this if you make new windows form project and insert my code and rss lnk and try to refresh it on button click.

Comment: I did exactly that. Inserted a (Windows Forms) button into your windows form and added my two lines of code which you can see below into the button click handler. Believe me or not, it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make data provider re-read its source:

```
var dataprovider = (System.Windows.Data.XmlDataProvider) (
  ((UserControl1) (elementHost1.Child)).Resources ["rssData"]
);
dataprovider.Refresh ();
```

Comment: Ill try that and let you know. Have you tested it?

Comment: partially. UserControl1 should be the class of your UserControl.

Comment: I have only added a elementhost from toolbox I havent created it manually as this wpfs tottaly new to me

Comment: you need not create it manually; your windows form class will contain a member representing the element host; btw. I have tried it now, and it works

Comment: Any idea why I am getting null exception when I put the link inside[ ] in what do you put it

Comment: What do you exactly put in the ["rssData"] ? When I put a link it doesn't work

Comment: You must put the link in the XML, rssData is the x:Key of you XmlDataProvider.

Answer (score 0):

What happens when you call your load event again?

Or at least the methods you are using to populate your data in the form>

i.e. either call your `this.Load(null,null)` (or pass some objects or events as needed)

```
private void form1_load(object o, EventArgs e)
{
    BindDataToControlMethod();
}
```

or have your code refactored so you can just call your `BindDataToControlMethod()` method(s).

The `elementHost1.Refresh()` call you are making just redraws the form on the screen. It does not reload per se.

Comment: this is a control that is loaded trough toolbox and this usercontrol is just as part of my screen which has a rss data and then I have a button for example which will be used as refresh. I don't want to load all form just only small port of it which calls usercontrol. That's the problem. If this is a full screen mode then I would load all form and done.

Comment: I think you can apply the same logic to a usercontrol as to the entire form. Both are objects which can be reinstantiated. If you need to filter your results when you make your call you'll have to do that on your own because there is not enough information here for me to try.

Comment: tell me what do you need as I don't understand exactly what you are saying. So I have one button and usercontrol which is loaded in elementHost1 trough the toolbox on windows form designer. That's all I have as I want to try how it works. Do you need a usercontrol code?

Comment: when your form loads, you then load your ElementHost. Within that you load your personally generated userControl. Is that right so far? How do you get your data into your usercontrol when it loads?

Comment: I have wrote usercontrol and I have made the file and it is in my project. I have added the elementhost from toolbox and it has a option to load wpf file if you have created one. So basically this is loaded when form starts. Data are loaded before as I am loading Drom RSS link

Comment: are you saying that you're loading the data at designtime NOT runtime?

Comment: I can try this again at home. I don't have Visual Studio in front of me.

Comment: Okay please do.. When can you do it?

Answer (score 0):

What about `MVVM` and `INotifyPropertyChanged`? 
Using `INotifyPropertyChanged` you can notify View when data has been changed and refresh it in this way. Seems like this is what you want.

---

Take a look into couple related links:

- [INotifyPropertyChanged WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1039505/inotifypropertychanged-wpf)
- [WPF/MVVM Quick Start Tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/165368/WPF-MVVM-Quick-Start-Tutorial)

Comment: That are really good articles. But this is for user form writtenin the c#.Imhave already created form as user control which is only loaded into elementhost control. I want to refresh it when button is pressed.

Comment: I have added the link where you can see the code of the user control

Answer (score 0):

As your Control is not refreshed automatically, I assume that you do not use data binding, which might be the best solution.

Suppose you have a user control with (custom) type UserControl1 hosting a button named MyButton.

You could either create a new WPF control and assign it to the child element, e.g.

```
((UserControl1) (elementHost1.Child)).MyButton = new System.Windows.Button ()
```

or you access the WPF control as follows

```
var wpfButton = ((UserControl1) (elementHost1.Child)).MyButton;
```

and then simply reset the necessary properties of the WPF control:

```
wpfButton.Content = "My new text";
```

EDIT: Mistakes corrected.

Comment: I have data binding as this user control is rss reader so I have data binding in it. I just want to refresh when button is clicked

Comment: I have added the link where you can see the code of the user control

Comment: But then you will probably want to make the XML data provider update, not one of your controls??? Give the data provider a name, access it via elementHost1.Child ["The name of the data provider"], cast this to an XmlDataProvider and call Refresh () on the data provider! See my other post.